# JavaScript head and tail on array without mutation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found about JavaScript array operations Unshift, shift, push, pop

However all these operations mutate the array.

Is there a way I could use these functions without causing mutation on the original data?

Somehow I feel that reading the data should not cause mutation.

Comment: You mean just accessing the indexes? Like `var test = [1, 2, 3, 4]; var a = test[test.length - 1]` where `a` now has the last element?

Comment: tail is not last element. yes indexers are easy. but I wanted to code without indexers and just access head/tail of array.

Comment: What should `push` that doesn't mutate the array do?

Comment: The whole point of pop() and shift() is that they remove the item from the array. And the point of an array is that it has numerically indexed items - why are you trying to complicate things by avoiding use of indices?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use:

```
var head = arr[0];
var tail = arr.slice(1);
```

Or in ES6:

```
const [head, ...tail] = arr;
```

Comment: And if you want to get the latest item, you can do arr.slice(-1)[0] (like with pop() but without mutating it).

Comment: What's the name of the kind of syntax used in the ES6 option?

Comment: @lalilulelost this is an array destructuring and the ... is a *gather*.

Answer (score 25):

I would do using ES6 as below

```
const head = ([h]) => h;
const tail = ([, ...t]) => t;

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

alert(head(arr));
```

Comment: That can be simplified with `const [head, ...tail] = [1,2,3,4,5]; alert(head);`

Comment: @RezaSaadati the point is that `head` and `tail` are separate functions that you can call later in your code.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is good, but for a more functional approach:

## Heads

I'd use find, which returns the first element that returns a true-thy value in its predicate.

If you are sure your values are true-thy, you can write it as follows:

```
arr.find(Boolean)
```

If you want the first value, regardless of its value, you can write it as follows:

```
arr.find(_ => true)
```

## Tails

Just as the others state, use slice

```
arr.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use lodash plugin which comes with **Array Manipulating Features**. Some of **javascript functions** operation given below without mutating the original array.

```js
var originalArray = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

//Equivalent of Unshift
let unshiftedArray = _.concat(["Lemon", "Pineapple"],originalArray);
console.log("unshiftedArray",unshiftedArray);

//Equivalent of shift
let shiftedArray = _.tail(originalArray);;
console.log("shiftedArray",shiftedArray);

//Equivalent of push
let pushedArray = _.concat(originalArray,'Lemon');
console.log("pushedArray",pushedArray);

//Equivalent of push
let poppedArray = _.dropRight(originalArray);
console.log("poppedArray",poppedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this method soon: [.at(index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(array.at(0));  //"a"
console.log(array.at(-1)); //"e"
```

Or you could use this method: [.slice(index)[0]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(array.slice(0)[0]);  //"a"
console.log(array.slice(-1))[0]; //"e"
```